Foundry library dependency mismatch
I have a foundry project making a custom dApp.
My dApp is heavily reliant on OpenZeppelin v4.
I recently installed uniswapV3 perifery and core in the project however I keep getting errors:

/lib/openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Metadata.sol": No such file or directory (os error 2); check configured remappings
--> /lib/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol
@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Metadata.sol


I cannot upgrade my project without having to refactor a large amount.
I don't want to copy the interfaces across, because they're dependent on a lot of other interface and it would be annoying.

Is there a way to simply remap only the files I need in the libraries, (Preferably without manually copying them which is what I did)?

Instead of manually copying the files,
you can install the required version of the OpenZeppelin library, by executing this command:
forge install openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@v4.x.x --no-commit

You need to replace v4.x.x in the above command with the exact v4 that you’re using in your dApp, like v4.9.5 or v4.9.6:
forge install openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@v4.9.6 --no-commit

And, in your foundry.toml, you just need to add the following remapping:
remappings = ['@openzeppelin/contracts=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts']


this won't work as uniswap references in their new file location.  I just want to override the location for 2 specific files.  For now I injected them in the lib, but that mean thats restore the project from github will break, and the audit might be worse.  I'd rather just override the specific file in the remappings or toml but idk if thats possible

If Uniswap periphery and core are the only libraries in your project that require Openzeppelin's contracts as a dependency, then you can try the following approach:
You can have your lib/openzeppelin-contracts correspond to the Uniswap's required 3.4.2 OZ library version by installing with forge install openzeppelin-contracts=openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.2-solc-0.7.
And then install the v4 OpenZeppelin contracts like: forge install openzeppelin-contracts-v4.0.0=openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.0.0 (or whatever nightly build or canary tag you prefer).
And you can just replace all references to the v4 OpenZeppelin's contracts codebase automatically in all of the your custom src/** or contracts/** (in VSCode it's very easy) by making sure that all of the references that you make in your source directory refer to openzeppelin-contracts-v4.0.0 instead of the openzeppelin-contracts remapping.
Hopefully, that helps.
I'm not sure whether there's any other way to override the version of the Foundry library used in the external dependency in a way that won't be overriden by continuous forge install in other versions of cloned Git repos, at least.
Other than this approach that I suggest or creating a fork/peer of the NPM package explicitly.
